# Can I open 2 transactions with different names

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

Can I have 2 transactions in a stored procedure like below? If I rollback TRAN1, does it rollback all TRAN2? I am lost here, any feedback will help. Thanks in advance

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION TRAN1

WHILE(...)
BEGIN

     BEGIN TRANSACTION TRAN2

     BEGIN TRY
           .....
           .....
           .....
           COMMIT TRANSACTION TRAN2         
     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TRAN2
     END CATCH
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION TRAN1
```

Comment: You might want to read this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter ,how many transactions you have ,Outer rollback rollbacks all the transactions..

When you nest transactions like in your case,each committ/rollback increases or decreases @@trancount..

From MSDN..

> Each BEGIN TRANSACTION statement increments @@TRANCOUNT by one. Each COMMIT TRANSACTION or COMMIT WORK statement decrements @@TRANCOUNT by one.
>
> ROLLBACK TRANSACTION that uses the transaction name of the outermost transaction in a set of nested transactions rolls back all of the nested transactions and decrements @@TRANCOUNT to 0

See this as well :[A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)

Below is demo to test this behaviour..

```
if object_id('t1','u') is not null
drop table t1

create table t1
(
id int
)

go

begin tran outertran

select @@trancount--1
insert into t1
select 1

begin tran innertran

select @@trancount--2

insert into t1
select 2



/**below throws error,since  you can reference only outer transaction
-referrring  inner tran is not legal
***/
--rollback tran   innertran

/*** 
error you get by uncommneting above
Msg 6401, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Cannot roll back innertran. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.
**/

commit tran innertran
select @@trancount--1

rollback --rollbacks all

select * from t1
```

References  :
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/